# Launching Custom Applications from the browser

Tags: web, hyperlink

I have been looking around SO and other on-line resources but cant seem to locate how this is done. I was wondering how things like magnet links worked on torrent website. They automatically open up and application and pass the appropriate params. I was wondering how could I create one to send a custom program params from the net?

Thanks

s654m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is an answer, but it is actually too long for a comment to fit.

Apps tend to register as authorities that can open a specific scheme. I don't know how it's done in desktop apps (especially because depending on each OS, it will vary), but on Android you can catch schemes or base urls by [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

The way it works (and I'm pretty sure the functionality is cross-OS) is:

1. Your app tells the system it can "read" a specific scheme or base url (it could be `magnet://` or even http://www.twitter.com/).
2. When you try to open a URI (Uniform resource identifier, a supergroup that can contain URLs), the system searches for any application that was registered for that kind of URI. I guess it runs from more specific and complete formats to the base. So for instance, this tweet: https://twitter.com/korcholis/status/491724155176222720 may be traced in this order:

   - https://twitter.com/korcholis/status/491724155176222720 Oh, no registrar? Moving on
   - https://twitter.com/korcholis/status Nothing yet? Ok
   - https://twitter.com/korcholis Nnnnnnope?
   - https://twitter.com Anybody? Ah, you, `Totally random name for a Twitter Client` know how to handle these links? Then it's yours
3. This random twitter client gets the full URI and does something accordingly.

As you see, nobody had a chance to track `https://`, since another application *caught* the URI before them. In this case, nobody could be your browsers.

It also defines, somehow, a default value. This is the true key why browsers tend to battle to be your *default browser of choice*. This just tells you they want to be the default applications that catch `http://`, `https://` and probably some more.

The true wonder here is that, as long as there's an app that catches a scheme, you can set the one you want. For instance, it's a common practice that apps from the same developer contain the same schemes, in case the developer wants to share tasks between them. This ensures the user will have to use a group of apps. So, one app can just offer data such as:

```
my-own-scheme://user/12
```

While another app is registered to get links that start with

```
my-own-scheme://
```

So, if you want to make your own schemes, it's ok, as long as they don't collide with other's. And if you want to read other's schemes, well, that's up to you to search for that. See? This is not a real answer, but I hope it removes almost all doubt.

Comment: Ahhh this was actually the kind of thing i was looking for! cheers!

Comment: @s654m great to know it helped you!